# How do I parse a multi nested (5/6) JSON object and convert it to a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

**Problem:** I have a multi nested JSON file that I need to parse and convert to a pandas dataframe where every field is a column. I've taken 2 approaches:

1. Convert raw file to data dictionary
2. Convert raw file to JSON object

**For data dictionary I've tried:**

- `df = pd.json_normalize(data)`

  - This leaves me with a DF that parses and loads up to `field12` (see dummy JSON below), the rest of the data is loaded into that single cell. Have also tried adding `max_level=` and I get the same result no matter what number I use
- I've tried `dt = dt.explode('field12')`

  - This leaves me with a single column of the headers in the 3rd nest with no data and the rest of the data is missing

**For JSON object I've tried:**

- `pd.read_json(json_object)`

  - This leaves me with a 4x9 table with the 1st column being the headers in the 2nd nest and the columns being the headers in the 1st nest, the rest of the data is stored in a single cell again

Please help, very lost with this one!

Below is a dummy JSON object that is an exact structure replica of the file I'm working with:

```
{
"field1":"dummyString",
"field2": null,
"field3":" dummyString",
"field4":{
"field5":" dummyString",
"field6":" dummyString",
"field7":" dummyString",
"field8":" dummyString",
"field9":"dummyNumber",
"field10":null,
"field11":" dummyString",
"field12":[
{
"field13":" dummyString",
"field14":" dummyString",
"field15":{
"field16":" dummyString",
"field17":" dummyString",
"field18":" dummyString"
},
"field19":" dummyString",
"field20":" dummyString",
"field21":" dummyString",
"field22":" dummyString",
"field23":" dummyString",
"field24": "dummyNumber",
"field25": "dummyNumber",
"field26":null,
"field27":" dummyString",
"field28":" dummyString",
"field29":" dummyString",
"field30": "dummyBoolean",
"field31": "dummyNumber",
"field32":" dummyString",
"field33":null,
"field34":[
{
"field35":"dummyString",
"field36":null,
"field37":{
"field38":"dummyString",
"field39":"dummyString",
"field40":" dummyString",
"field41":" dummyString",
"field42":" dummyString",
"field43":" dummyString",
"field44":null,
"field45":" dummyString",
"field46":" dummyString"
},
"field47":null,
"field48":null,
"field49":null,
"field50":null,
"field51": "dummyNumber",
"field52":"dummyString",
"field53":"dummyString",
"field54":"dummyBoolean",
"field55": "dummyBoolean",
"field56":"dummyString",
"field57":null,
"field58":null
},{
"field59":{
"field60":null,
"field61":null,
"field62":null

    } 
}
]

}
],
"field63":"dummyStringl"


}
}
```

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: A dataframe where every field is a column is the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to flatten a dict like yours.

```
def flatten(d):
    ret = {**d}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            ret.pop(k)
            ret = {**ret, **flatten(v)}
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            ret.pop(k)
            for item in v:
                ret = {**ret, **flatten(item)}
            
    return ret

df = pd.json_normalize(flatten(j))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        field1 field2        field3        field5        field6        field7        field8       field9 field10  ...       field41       field42       field43 field44       field45       field46 field60 field61 field62
0  dummyString   None   dummyString   dummyString   dummyString   dummyString   dummyString  dummyNumber    None  ...   dummyString   dummyString   dummyString    None   dummyString   dummyString    None    None    None

[1 rows x 57 columns]
```